# replace a string from first line on multiple files

Tags: perl, file, unix, replace, sed

I got 10,000 text files which I have to make changes.

First line on every file contains a url.

By mistake for few files url missking 'com'

```
eg:
1) http://www.supersonic./psychology 
2) http://www.supersonic./social
3) http://www.supersonic.com/science
```

my task is to check and add 'com' if it is missing

```
eg:
    1) http://www.supersonic.com/psychology 
    2) http://www.supersonic.com/social
    3) http://www.supersonic.com/science
```

all urls are of same domain(supersonic.com)

can you suggest me any fast and easy approach ?

Tried this : replacing `supersonic./` with `supersonic.com`

```
sed -e '1s/supersonic.//supersonic.com/' *
```

no change in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with your code, but you need to account for the trailing `/` char after the `.` char.

Assuming you are using a modern `sed` with the `-i` (inplace-edit) option you can do

```
sed -i '1s@supersonic\./@supersonic.com/@' *
```

Note that rather than have to escape `/` inside of the `s/srchpat\/withSlash/replaceStr/'`, you can use another char after the the `s` command as the delimiter, here I use `s@...@...@`. If your search pattern had a `@` char, then you would have to use a different char.

Some older versions of `sed` need to you to escape the alternate delimiter at the first use, so

```
     sed 's\@srchStr@ReplStr@' file
```

for those cases.

If you're using a `sed` that doesn't support the `-i` options, then 
you'll need to loop on your file, and manage the tmp files, i.e.

```
 for f in *.html ; do
    sed '1s@supersonic\./@supersonic.com/@' "$f" > /tmp/"$f".fix \
    && /bin/mv /tmp/"$f".fix "$f"
 done
```

**Warning**

But as you're talking about 10,000+files, you'll want to do some testing before using either of these solutions. Copy a good random set of those files to /tmp/mySedTest/ dir and run one of these solutions there to make sure there are no surprises.

And you're likely to blow out the cmd-line MAX_SIZE with 10,000+ files, so read about find and xargs. There are many posts here about `[sed] find xargs`. Check them out if needed.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `-i` to change the files instead of just outputting the changed lines.
2. Use a different delimiter than `/` if you want to use `/` in the regex (or use `\/` in the regex).
3. Use `\.` to match a dot literally, `.` matches anything.

   ```
   sed -i~ -e '1s=supersonic\./=supersonic.com/=' *
   ```

Some versions of `sed` don't support `-i`.